# How to pass command line arguments to a docker image

Tags: docker

I run tests inside docker image and I need to pass custom arguments 
all the time.

When I put arguments after image name docker thinks that argument is image name.

```
docker run  -t -i image-name -s test.py
docker run  -t -i image-name -- -s test.py
```

Error:

```
Failed no image test_arena2.py
```

Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9

Comment: It would be really helpful if you extracted a [mcve].

Answer (score 9):

You can build your Dockerfile with a combination of `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` instructions, which will let you [run containers with or without arguments](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/entrypoint), e.g:

```
FROM ubuntu
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/echo"]
CMD ["hello"]
```

That says the entrypoint is the `echo` command, and the default argument is `hello`. Run a container with no arguments:

```
> docker run temp
hello
```

Run with arguments and they all get passed to the entrypoint command:

```
> docker run temp -s stackoverflow
-s stackoverflow
```

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

`docker run -i` is good to be the begin of your command line then `set of arguments for the run command` only then at the very last `-t image` with image name provided

Answer (score -2):

Image name should always be at the end of docker run command i.e. as last parameter to the command. Are you fine with passing the values as environment variable using below command

```
docker run -e "ENV_VAR_NAME=VALUE" -it image_name
```